# Cannot access wp admin of Wordpress website (security plugin issue)

Tags: security

I was using all in one WP security and White Label plugin in one of my wordpress website. 
I had custom wp-admin login url. After moving host i realized i cannot login via custom url. Also, wp-admin is not working. 
I tried editing/deleting .htaccess, rename plugin folder and plugin but no luck. 
Even tried to disable plugins via php admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall WordPress manually, **don't delete your wp-content folder** and unzip the file from https://wordpress.org/latest.zip.

Check this Article https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update

Thanks !!!